# Erc20 token minting based on api variable

Tags: erc-20, external-api

Can I have a erc20 coin contract that watches an API and mints coins and distributes them evenly to the network based on a changing variable in said API?

Comment: What is the API used to modify the erc20 token structure?

Comment: Twitch api from twitch.tv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smart contracts can't continuously run and monitor something. They have to be poked (via a transaction) to do anything. They also can't communicate with an external API.

The typical solution for this sort of thing is an "oracle." Essentially, something (not a smart contract) monitors the API and sends the result into the smart contract. This creates a point of centralization, so companies like [Oraclize](http://www.oraclize.it/) have popped up to act as that centralized entity and be trusted by virtue of having a stellar reputation of "telling the truth" to the blockchain.

Answer (score 1):

Oraclize is a good solution to use but it can be quite costly. Personally I would write a very simple script using web3py or web3js to check the twitch.tv api every so often for whatever particular state change you are looking for, and then mint the appropriate amount of tokens by initiating a transaction calling the token minting function.